# React useEffect async warning?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, asynchronous, react-hooks

I'm trying to get rid of React's warning "It looks like you wrote useEffect(async () => ...) or returned a Promise. Instead, write the async function inside your effect and call it immediately".

I've been referencing this article https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data to attempt to get rid of it, but alas, am unable to.

My useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => api.getAllPokemon(setResponse),[])
```

And my api.getAllPokemon async function which I've defined in an imported file:

```
const api = {}

api.getAllPokemon = async (cb) => {
  await fetch('http://localhost:8080/pokemon', {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then(async (pokemon) => await pokemon.json())
  .then((pokemon) => pokemon.rows.map(({ name }) => name))
  .then(pokemon => cb(pokemon))
};

export default api;
```

Comment: i don't have enough streetcred on SO for my upvote to go public

Comment: But you can accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

`useEffect` can only return a cleanup function or nothing. In your case, add brackets to your arrow function or use the normal function syntax to avoid returning a Promise:

```
useEffect(() => {
  api.getAllPokemon(setResponse)
}, [])
```

or

```
useEffect(function () { 
  api.getAllPokemon(setResponse) 
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

u cant combine await and also promise

and also async in useEffect has a little different.

when you async your fetch .then doesn't work but it returns the response for you

so we need to write try and catch

```
useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/pokemon");
        setBaseExperience(res);
      };

      fetchData();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON fetching example using fetch wrapper ([Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-effect-demo1-vho29?from-embed=&file=/src/TestComponent.js))

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useAsyncEffect } from "use-async-effect2";
import cpFetch from "cp-fetch"; //cancellable c-promise fetch wrapper

export default function TestComponent(props) {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  useAsyncEffect(
    function* () {
      setText("fetching...");
      const response = yield cpFetch(props.url);
      const json = yield response.json();
      setText(`Success: ${JSON.stringify(json)}`);
    },
    [props.url]
  );

  return <div>{text}</div>;
}
```

According to your code:

```
const api = {}

api.getAllPokemon = function*() => {
  const respose= yield cpFetch('http://localhost:8080/pokemon', {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  });

  const pokemon= yield response.json();
  return pokemon.rows.map(({ name }) => name));
};

export default API;
```

Inside the functional component body:

```
useAsyncEffect(function*(){
   const names= yield* api.getAllPokemon(setResponse);
   // changeState here
},[])
```